# bug in error messages in IE 10

Tags: bug, javascript, error-message, internet-explorer-10

While using Internet Explorer 10, I am having problems MOST OF THE TIME when creating a new question, editing a question, or checking a question for the correct answer when there is a validation error.

I.E.  I click "Ask Question"  ->  "Post Your Question" without typing any input.

I get "An error occurred submitting your question." in the red box below the "Post Your Question" button.  None of the right-sided bullets are there to tell you what errors you have.

Now in Chrome, Opera, or Firefox I get "Your question couldn't be submitted. Please see the errors above." right above the "Post Your Question" submit button; there is also three right side bullets: "Title is missing.", "Body is missing", and "Please enter at least one tag..."

Sometimes I have found there is an error while trying to submit a change or new question without me knowing what the error is.

Another example: I tried to edit THIS message in IE and I got an error message without knowing what the error is.

Thanks

[image]

Comment: You will need a picture... with a circle... one that is red...

Comment: @Jonathan What kind of errors are you talking about here? Errors like a page failing to load (404, but IE doesn't tell you), or errors like being unable to edit a comment because you're past the 5 minute window?

Comment: I have edited this message to be more specific and added an image. Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Not gonna try and verify this, but... Make sure you're not somehow loading the page in Compatibility Mode. Sooo many problems end up being that. Glad they finally hid that damn button in IE11.

Comment: Yeah, compatibility mode doesn't even show that there is an error. So that is not the case.  Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem. The problem was occurring with [Speedbit's Download Accelerator Plus](http://www.speedbit.com/). I did some testing to make sure that was the problem. Once I uninstalled the program, voila: no more issues with IE10. I'm going to keep the program uninstalled for good.